# How to update selenium to 3.9 through conda

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda

How to update selenium to 3.9 through conda? I was not able to install selenium through pip so installed it through Anaconda command prompt but I need version of selenium to be 3.9

Answer (score 3):

You can do it through Anaconda command prompt or the Anaconda Navigator.

Through the Anaconda command prompt:
Make sure you double check your environment and then `conda update selenium`. This will ask you to confirm upgrade of dependent packages as well.

Through the Navigator:
Select the environment that you're using. Scroll to select the `selenium` package and click on the blue version number to the right - `4.6.0` in my example of `beautifulsoup4` shown in the image.

[image]

Click apply and confirm upgrade to a list of all dependent packages as well.